# WYSIWYG textarea component security

Tags: php, textarea, wysiwyg, user-input, validation

Really my question has more to do with the server-side scrubbing of html that's accepted via the WYSIWYG form component.  Right now I'm leaning toward using htmlpurifier.org's library.  I'm using php strip_tags() function elsewhere.  Anyone have an advice/preferences/recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strip_tags` is very vulnerable - you might as well do nothing. HtmlPurifier is probably as good as it gets with html-cleansing. If you are really serious about security, you should probably disallow html input entirely, but I realise that's not always an option.

Comment: Oh, trust me, I've fought for disallowing it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to scrub out the `on*` attributes like `<p onclick="alert('hi!');">`.
This can cause some trouble.